# Fast jitter library

Tags: compiler-construction, jit

Anything out there other than llvm ? libjit doesn't seem very active.. I need a really fast and stable jitter. Even at the expense of features.. (preferably under c++)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, libjit is fairly stable, ie it might be a viable option even if it's inactive. Some other alternatives are [GNU lightning](http://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/) and Mozilla's [Nanojit](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Nanojit).

Comment: If you need fast and stable jit for Linux, then probably you really stuck with mono and llvm.

By the way, what's wrong with llvm, why it does not fit?

Comment: llvm is wonderful. I really enjoy working with it. I just wonder about any faster alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Mono, Microsoft .NET, JVM. They all are quite embeddable into a C++ application.